# P2OS for ROS Kinetic on Debian Stretch

Tags: ros, p2os, pioneer-3dx, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on a Pioneer-3dx and was hoping to use the sonar data (as we only have sonar on it yet) to make it follow a moving object. I know I could juste use RosAria to get informations from the sonar but I also need to simulate it on Gazebo, thus I was advised p2os.

The problem is that I can't find a way to get p2os on Kinetic ROS for Debian Stretch. If someone could help me or provide me a link, I would warmly thank him.

Hdifsttar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262434/p2os-for-ros-kinetic-on-debian-stretch/) by [Hdifsttar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30367/hdifsttar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-08-03**:
Did you try to `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-p2os*`? There are debians generated for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, referenced in both the [targeted platforms page](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) and the [installation instructions for Debian Kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebianSources.Setup_your_sources.list), Kinetic only supports Debian Jessie. [ROS Lunar](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019) and [Melodic](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023) will support Debian Stretch, as can be seen on the [install instructions for Debian Lunar](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian). I believe you can compile Kinetic from source on Stretch, but I probably recommend going through that trouble.

After going through the Lunar install setup for Debian Stretch, you should be able to install via

`$ sudo apt install ros-lunar-p2os*`

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1